# Switch case in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, switch-statement

These are my `UIButtons`

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnProgressDate: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnClosedDate: UIButton!
```

I have dragged these two buttons for the action as:

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let tag = sender.tag
    self.clearPopups()
    switch (tag) {
            case 1:
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = nil

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed
        }
        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate, animated: true)
        }
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnProgressDate
    case 2:
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate
        }

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed, animated: true)
        }
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnClosedDate
    default:
        print("Proper btn not found")
    }


}
```

But every time I clicked to any of the buttons **default** case will be executed. I am totally new to swift. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: did you print button tag ?

Comment: initially i have set to tag 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `tag`, In your action method can use `IBOutlet` of `UIButton` that you have created like this way.

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.clearPopups()
    if sender == btnProgressDate {
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = nil

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed
        }
        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate, animated: true)
        }
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnProgressDate
    }
    else if sender == btnClosedDate {
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate
        }

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed, animated: true)
        }
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnClosedDate
    }
    else {
        print("Proper btn not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't i put different dates to the button? this is letting me just to put same dates in both buttons

Comment: @Nirojthapa Can you explain more, don't get what you try to say is.

Comment: @Nirojthapa Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is totally obvious but have you actually set the tag properties for the buttons? Your code looks totally fine to me so I can't think of any other reason you are seeing this problem.

Comment: Just a comment to this. A quick `print(tag)` just after this line: `let tag = sender.tag` should let you see what the value of `tag` actually is. I'm guessing it'll be 0 for the reasons @jacob-king suggests above.

Comment: Initally tag is set to 0

Comment: Well there is your problem, the tag is 0 but you are checking if it is 1 or 2. Its 0 so default is getting hit.

Comment: If the buttons are in storyboard, change their tag property in attribute inspector, if they are programatic set them in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.clearPopups()
    switch sender {
    case btnProgressDate:
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = nil

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed
        }

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate, animated: true)
        }
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnProgressDate
    case btnClosedDate:
        self.datePicker.hidden = false
        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = self.healthActionPlanCondition.nextProgressReviewDate
        }

        if(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed != nil)
        {
            self.datePicker.datePicker.setDate(self.healthActionPlanCondition.dateClosed, animated: true)
        }
        self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = nil
        self.selectedBtn = self.btnClosedDate
    default:
        print("Proper btn not found")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set initially tag 0 .Just Set tag 1 for first button and tag 2 for second button.